# ValidationError: "value must be a decimal number"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following Model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="Listings")
    category = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField()
    starting_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=decimal.Decimal(0))
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=starting_price)
```

In my views.py I use an instance of a Django Form class to ask the user for the input.
I get the following error ['“auctions.Listing.starting_price” value must be a decimal number.']
However, when I check the Local Vars on the error page I can see the the value of `starting_price = Decimal('10.00')`

So clearly the value of auctions.Listing.starting_price is a decimal! There are no other entries which could cause this problem.

The Form I use looks like that:

```
class NewListingForm(forms.Form):
    product = forms.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    category = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=False)
    starting_price = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)
```

When Posting I evalute the data like so:

```
if entry_form.is_valid():
    product = entry_form.cleaned_data["product"]
    description = entry_form.cleaned_data["description"]
    category = entry_form.cleaned_data["category"]
    starting_price = entry_form.cleaned_data["starting_price"]
```

And I save the model entry via:

```
listing = Listing(product=product, description=description, user=user, category=category, created=created, starting_price=starting_price)
listing.save()
```

I'd really appreciate any ideas on that.

Comment: You can not ues `default=starting_price`, since `starting_price` is a `DecimalField` object, not a `Decimal`. You need to set both `starting_price` and `current_price`. For example with `Listing(product=product, description=description, user=user, category=category, created=created, starting_price=starting_price, current_price=starting_price)`

Comment: Awesome, that fixed it!

Comment: I would also remove the `default=...` since that will not work, and likely only cause problems :s.

Comment: The reason i did this because while searching for this issue this problem often occured with empty entries of type "". Therefore, setting the default to a valid decimal should avoid this issue should somehow an entry oocur without a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the `default=starting_price` part:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    # …
    current_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=starting_price
    )
```

When the class itself is interpreted, `starting_price` is a `DecimalField`, so it will try to assign a `DecimalField` as *value* to another `DecimalField`, *not* a `Decimal`. Since a `DecimalField` accepts certain types of objects like strings, `Decimal`s, etc. but not a `DecimalField`, that will raise an error.

You can simply pass the value to both the `starting_price` and `current_price`, for example:

```
Listing.objects.create(
    product=product,
    description=description,
    user=user,
    category=category,
    created=created,
    starting_price=starting_price,
    current_price=starting_price
)
```